# SQL - Join on changing dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've been scratching my head on this for a week now.

Consider two tables - one tallying inventory:

```
+------------+--------------+----------+-------------------+
| product_id | product_name |   date   | on_hand_inventory |
+------------+--------------+----------+-------------------+
|          1 | Product A    | 6/1/2019 |                37 |
|          1 | Product A    | 6/2/2019 |                36 |
|          1 | Product A    | 6/3/2019 |                35 |
|          1 | Product A    | 6/4/2019 |                40 |
|          1 | Product A    | 6/5/2019 |                42 |
+------------+--------------+----------+-------------------+
```

...  and another tracking costs:

```
+------------+----------------+------------+------------+------------+
| product_id | cost_component | cost_value | start_date |  end_date  |
+------------+----------------+------------+------------+------------+
|          1 | FOB            |         15 | 1/1/2019   | 6/1/2019   |
|          1 | FOB            |       15.5 | 6/2/2019   | 6/3/2019   |
|          1 | FOB            |         16 | 6/4/2019   | 12/31/9999 |
+------------+----------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

The layout of the cost table is what's driving me nuts. I need to join these
tables to keep a running valuation of on-hand inventory, and I can't think of a 
method in SQL that would let me select the appropriate row in the cost table.
A join on produt_id doesn't work because it would return all cost components for
that item whether or not they apply to that date. I feel like should be
involving a `CASE` statement, but I'm not sure what that would look like.
This is in MSSQL 2016, for what its worth.

Comment: Will a `cost_value` for a single `product_id` ever have an `end_date` that is the same `start_date` for a new `cost_value` with the same `product_id`? Meaning, will the cost ever change the same day?

Comment: I don't believe so, there are no time components in either of the date fields. At any rate, I've been operating under the assumption that costs cannot change on the same day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the most recent cost, you can use `join`:

```
select t.*, c.*
from inventory i join
     costs c
     on c.product_id = i.product_id and
        i.date between c.start_date and c.end_date;
```

Comment: Beat me by this much. > <  I recommend adding an index on start_date and end_date to improve performance as well.

Comment: Oh my God, I'm an idiot - of COURSE I can use between in a join clause, why the heck WOULDN'T I be able to do that?!?

Thanks for the assist!