# SQL - Raising the bar: Query within a threshold

Tags: sql, sql-server

Related to my previous question: [SQL - Join on changing dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59651362/sql-join-on-changing-dates/59651446#59651446) - the situation is more complicated than I thought it was.

Consider the following two tables - one tallying inventory:

```
+------------+--------------+----------+-------------------+
| product_id | product_name |   date   | on_hand_inventory |
+------------+--------------+----------+-------------------+
|          1 | Product A    | 6/1/2019 |                37 |
|          1 | Product A    | 6/2/2019 |                36 |
|          1 | Product A    | 6/3/2019 |                35 |
|          1 | Product A    | 6/4/2019 |                40 |
|          1 | Product A    | 6/5/2019 |                42 |
+------------+--------------+----------+-------------------+
```

... and another tracking costs:

```
+------------+----------------+------------+------------+------------+
| product_id | cost_component | cost_value | start_date |  end_date  |
+------------+----------------+------------+------------+------------+
|          1 | FOB            |         15 | 1/1/2019   | 12/31/9999 |
|          1 | FOB            |       15.5 | 6/2/2019   | 12/31/9999 |
|          1 | FOB            |         16 | 6/4/2019   | 12/31/9999 |
+------------+----------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

So it turns out that `costs.end_date` has been badly maintained, and contains many duplicate end dates. The following query:

```
SELECT T1.product_name,
       T1.date,
       T1.on_hand_inventory,
       T2.cost_value
  FROM inventory T1
 INNER JOIN costs T2
         ON T1.product_id = T2.product_id
        AND T1.date BETWEEN T2.start_date AND T2.end_date
```

Produces this result:

```
+------------+--------------+----------+-------------------+----------------+-------+
| product_id | product_name |   date   | on_hand_inventory | cost_component | value |
+------------+--------------+----------+-------------------+----------------+-------+
|          1 | Product A    | 6/1/2019 |                37 | FOB            |    15 |
|          1 | Product A    | 6/1/2019 |                37 | FOB            |  15.5 |
|          1 | Product A    | 6/1/2019 |                37 | FOB            |    16 |
|          1 | Product A    | 6/2/2019 |                36 | FOB            |  15.5 |
|          1 | Product A    | 6/2/2019 |                36 | FOB            |    16 |
|          1 | Product A    | 6/3/2019 |                35 | FOB            |  15.5 |
|          1 | Product A    | 6/3/2019 |                35 | FOB            |    16 |
|          1 | Product A    | 6/4/2019 |                40 | FOB            |    16 |
|          1 | Product A    | 6/5/2019 |                42 | FOB            |    16 |
+------------+--------------+----------+-------------------+----------------+-------+
```

Note the duplicate cost values for several dates.

I feel like `APPLY` might be a place to start, but I'm not certain...

Comment: I see the issue but what do you want as output? Which row in the second table is the "correct" one?

Comment: It should use whichever cost component is "current" for that date - The 6/1 inventory should show 15, the 6/3 should show 15.5, etc.

Comment: That is my point exactly. How do you know which one is "current" There are multiples that have overlapping date ranges. Why is 15.5 more correct than 15 for 6/3? They both meet the criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `outer apply`.  This focuses only on the start date:

```
SELECT i.*, c.*
FROM inventory i OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT TOP (1) c.*
      FROM costs c
      WHERE i.product_id = i.product_id AND
            i.date >= c.start_date
      ORDER BY c.start_date DESC
     ) c;
```

Ironically, this was my first answer to your previous question.  I rewrote the answer when I saw the end date.

Another approach is to use `LEAD()` to get the next end date:

```
SELECT i.*, c.*
FROM inventory i LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT c.*,
             LEAD(start_date) OVER (PARTITION BY product_id ORDER BY start_date) as next_start_date
      FROM costs c
     ) c
     ON i.product_id = i.product_id AND
        i.date >= c.start_date AND
        (i.date < c.next_start_date OR c.next_start_date IS NULL);
```

Comment: Is there any particular benefit to selecting the top row of an ordered set instead of, say, grouping and selecting the max start date?

Comment: @Nightglow . . . `APPLY` is often faster, so the first method would be better.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend cleaning up the costs.end_date if you have access to, but going on the assumption that the most recent start_date is correct, you are correct with using an APPLY operator.

```
SELECT T1.product_name,
       T1.date,
       T1.on_hand_inventory,
       T2.cost_value
  FROM inventory T1
 CROSS APPLY(SELECT TOP 1 c.cost_value
           FROM Costs c 
           WHERE T1.product_id = c.product_id
                AND T1.date >= c.start_date 
           ORDER BY c.start_date DESC) t2
```

Answer (score 1):

You would have to manipulate the end date in the costs table a bit before using it in the join. Assuming the start and end dates are continuous:

```
SELECT T1.product_name,
       T1.date,
       T1.on_hand_inventory,
       T2.cost_value
  FROM inventory T1
 INNER JOIN (select *,ISNULL(lead(DATEADD(day,-1,start_date),1) Over(Partition by product_id order by start_date),'12-31-9999') as end_date1 from costs) T2
         ON T1.product_id = T2.product_id
        AND T1.date BETWEEN T2.start_date AND T2.end_date1
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Clever! I love the use of `LEAD` here. I ended up using the `OUTER APPLY` method instead, but still - great answer!